# Email on failure is not sent sendgrid/cloud composer

Tags: sendgrid, google-cloud-composer

I've been using sendgrid to alert people on task failure in cloud composer. But email not been arriving to my email list even after failure also. Please find below default argument list

```
default_dag_args = {
    "start_date": "2019-02-25",
    # Email whenever an Operator in the DAG fails.
    "email":[email_list]
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'project_id': PROJECT_ID
}
```

And i've add environment variable also SENDGRID_MAIL_FROM and SENDGRID_API_KEY. But still on failure i'm not receiving any alert mail.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not yet, I'd strongly recommend double-checking the [instructions for setting up SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#configuring_sendgrid_email_services) with Cloud Composer. Make sure of a few things:

1. You set up the environment variable through the mechanism (editing the environment) as the guide says
2. Try sending a test DAG, as the guide says

If that continues to fail, I'd then start suspecting a firewall rule (if you have edited them) may be causing the issue. **Be careful if you are adjusting firewall rules.**

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem, the DAG's task log was just displaying this error:

```
python_http_client.exceptions.ForbiddenError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I fixed it by setting `SENDGRID_MAIL_FROM` to an email address (mine) that was verified in SendGrid. Before I was using a non verified address, such as `noreply@mycompany.com`.

Follow these [docs](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/senders) to add a sender and - if needed - verify it via the verification link in the email you'll receive.